# PIL installation error in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I'm tyring to install PIL to Heroku, because I seem to need it for Django-Avatar.

so I put it in my requirements.txt, but when installing it gives me the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

```
   /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have no clue how to solve this.

I've done some research and it looks like other packages had suffered from the same error such as **reportlab**, diagnosing for that case:

> The problem seems to be caused by the presence of a static Python 2.7 library in /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a

and then a newer version of reportlab was released to bypass the crash. That's not the case with PIL, could somebody point me out what to do?

thanks

Comment: r u tried to install PIL in heroku bash ..?

Comment: PIL is pretty much abandonware at this point. Try [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: The same happens with Pillow 2.2.1, just answer the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Use this PIL fork at your `requirements.txt`:

```
wsgiref==0.1.2
-e hg+https://bitbucket.org/etienned/pil-2009-raclette/#egg=PIL
pyyaml
```

It solves this issue.